# Postman giving error for pre-request script

Tags: javascript, postman

Using below snippet:

```
var timestamp = $.now().toString();
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("timestamp", timestamp);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("apikey", obfuscateApiKey('yourapikey', timestamp));
```

Getting error: There was an error in evaluating the Pre-request Script:  ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Not good in JavaScript, need to check.

Comment: Sounds like you need to include jquery. Also, not sure this has anything to do with java...

Comment: Do you mean Postman, the API testing app? What do you do exactly? Seems to me that you're just missing a lib like jQuery that defines the `$`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

var timestamp = (new Date).getTime().toString(); 
instead of 
var timestamp = $.now().toString();

Answer (score 1):

Postman doesn't use jQuery, but you can use a cutdown version of it called CheerioJS, see the documentation [here](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio).

It doesn't support now() but from the jQuery documentation for now():

> The $.now() method is a shorthand for the number returned by the expression (new Date).getTime()

So you can just use the standard javascript here.

See [this postman blog post](http://blog.getpostman.com/2016/08/30/jquery-replaced-by-cheeriojs-in-postman-sandbox/) for more info on using CheerioJS within postman.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this without the need to use CheerioJS in Postman.

You could use the built-in `{{$timestamp}}` global variable that gets created at runtime but that only seems to work in URL, Headers etc.

So you could just do this, for example:

```
var timestamp = (new Date).getTime().toString()
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("apikey", obfuscateApiKey('yourapikey', 
timestamp))
```

Comment: I would go with this or something like it, because it's simple, and fast. (plain javascript)

You should also check out the libraries Postman supports: https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/postman_sandbox

Some of them could save you a fair bit of time.